# Linux aliases not working when changing users

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Using Debian 10.11

I created file in `/etc/profile.d` and named it `bash_aliases.sh`. In this file I added one alias:

```
alias ll='ls -la'
```

When starting new session, alias works as expected. However, when changing to root by using `sudo su` the alias stops working:

```
bash: ll: command not found
```

I'd like to have this alias working all the time. Any way to do so?

Comment: Try running `sudo -i su` where `-i` is "(simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. "

Comment: has root this aliases also defined? if not, thatd a normal behavior. you may need to use either the system wide alias or when its the same, either sudo -i or su -l

Comment: @DavidPostill it actually works with `sudo su -`

Comment: @djdomi I defined alias in `/etc/profile.d` because I thought that `/etc/profile` would distribute it to all the users (because in `/etc/profile` there is a part that loads all *.sh from `/etc/profile.d`)

Answer (score 0):

For the root user the easy way is to add the alias to the root `.bashrc`, the full path is `/root/.bashrc`.

Or add it `/root/.bash_aliases` because in your root `.bashrc` you have this test command:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Use:

```
echo "alias ll='ls -la'" | sudo tee -a /root/.bashrc
sudo su
exec bash
```